# Find nearest proportions algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Given I have an array of proportions (3 values that in total produce 100%):

`var proportions = [[10,10,80],[20,30,50],[40,20,40],[0,0,100]];`

How do I sort the array in the order of proximity(distance) to any one given proportion?

For example,`sortProportions(proportions, [22,28,50])` would return `[[20,30,50],[10,10,80],[40,20,40],[0,0,100]]`.

Here [20,30,50] is the first, because it is the closest proportion to  [22,28,50]. Not sure for the other, though.

In math terms it is called a **ternary plot**. The problem boils down to finding the distance between the two points on a ternary plot.

Comment: don´t really understand what the proximity would be, could you give an example of a proportion and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean a sum of squares of differences for each dimension proximity

```
function distance2(p1, p2) {
    return Math.pow(p1[0] - p2[0], 2) + Math.pow(p1[1] - p2[1], 2) + Math.pow(p1[2] - p2[2], 2)
}

// given point
var gP = [20, 30, 55];

// sort 
var output = [[10, 10, 80], [20, 30, 50], [40, 20, 40], [0, 0, 100]].sort(function (a, b) {
    // -1 if a before b
    //  1 if a after b
    //  0 if no change
    return Math.sign(distance2(a, gP) - distance2(b, gP));
});
```

Comment: Do we really need squares? These are not points in 3-dimentional space

Comment: Ah! I put this in before your edit adding more details :-). But anyhoo, all you have to do is change the distance2 function. First translate each point to cartesian (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot > Plotting a Ternary plot > the last formula) to get (x, y) for each [a, b, c]. And then do (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2